# GitBash not outputting to console

Tags: git-bash

GitBash suddenly stopped working correctly. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling with no avail.

git commands seem to execute, but doesn't show anything in the console. For instance, I can pull, push, init and it works, but nothing shows on the command line.

`git --version` doesn't return anything to the console.

However, if I output it to a file with `git --version > output.txt`, it shows correctly in the file.

Also doesn't show the current branch on the command line. Newly reinstalled. Am I missing some config or is it some windows issues, or something else?

I'm running git version 2.19.2.windows.1 on windows 7.

git --version in the windows command line works fine, but not in GitBash.

Comment: what error you are getting??
are you getting this error 
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: @rykamol No errors. It just doesn't return anything.

Comment: note: similar question here at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968628/git-bash-for-windows-gives-no-result-and-returns-to-command-prompt

Comment: @BiAiB What version of Git are you using, on which Windows?

Comment: @VonC Windows 7, git version 2.18.0.windows.1

Comment: @BiAiB Would the issue persists with Git 2.21?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am in an environment where I 'm not admin and can't install stuff

Comment: I reformatted my computer since then and unable to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 3):

That has happened to me a few times in Windows. In each case, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073577) held the secret.

> In my case, the cursor didn't move, or show my typing onscreen.
>   However, it actually executed the command (if I pressed Enter), even though it looked like I didn't type anything in!
>
> The solution was to type **reset** < Enter >

Answer (score 2):

Try and re-install [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), possibly through the portable versionl like [`PortableGit-2.20.0.rc2.windows.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.20.0-rc2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.20.0.rc2.windows.1-64-bit.7z.exe) (an archive you can uncompress anywhere you want), and a [simplified `PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45779657/6309).

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Then check in that session (the one with said simplified path) if the issue persists.

Comment: Issue still persists. It's fine if I run git --version in the windows command line, but not in GitBash

I don't think the path is the issue. In GitBash, if I nagivate to git.exe in Portable Git/bin, and run ./git.exe --version, the issue of not showing anything in the console is still there.   




`$ echo $PATH
`/c/Users/lauv.CORPDOM/Desktop/PortableGit/bin:/c/Users/lauv.CORPDOM/Desktop/PortableGit/usr/bin:/c/Users/lauv.CORPDOM/Desktop/PortableGit/mingw64/bin:/c/windows/system32:/c/windows:/c/windows/system32/wbem:/c/windows/system32/windowspowershell/v1.0

Comment: @vvvvv I suppose the result is the same without navigating to the bin folder, typing simply `git --version`? (no `.exe` should be needed)

Comment: Yes, that's right. Simply calling git --version and running the executable directly both doesn't return anything to the console.

Comment: @vvvvv Strange: some kind of stdout/stderr redirection issue.