# Malloc Failed in Git Clone

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, git-bash, dvcs

Using Git version 2.19.1.windows.1 on Windows 7 64 bit.

I am trying to run in *D:/Users/Della/Documents/Python_Scripts/*

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/forkingpin/dui-dashboard.git
```

on the git bash. The repository contains only a 59 bytes ReadMe so far. The error message I am getting reads

```
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 1744830464 bytes)
fatal: not a git repository: 'D:/Users/Della/Documents/Python_Scripts/
```

What is the way out?

Points to note.

- The same command is working like a charm on my Linux Desktop
- I had a similar issue while pushing the committed changes (on windows) in another repository. I corrected that by appending .git/config with

  ```
  [http]                                                         
        postbuffer = 5m
  ```

But that was for an existing repository. I cannot have the config file before I clone it.

Answer (score 0):

Try if the same command works in a regular CMD (not git bash), where you have set [a simplified PATH first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53606336/6309):

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%

cd D:\Users\Della\Documents\Python_Scripts
git clone https://gitlab.com/forkingpin/dui-dashboard.git
cd dui-dashboard
dir
```