# how to save commit message using atom

Tags: git, atom-editor, git-bash

I have an issue with saving commit message using Atom. I know there is an alternative to make commit with description using this
`git commit -m "Title" -m "Description .........."`
but I am committed with course track. 
anyway, all I do ***my steps to make commit until I get the error message*** is in the following YouTube video.

[my problem with Atom to save commit message and exit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89f8lG_lh7s)
.

ultimately, I got this error message

> Attempting to call a function in a renderer window that has been closed or released.
>   Function provided here: Object. (C:\Users\Kimo Store\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.33.0\resources\app.asar\node_modules\github\lib\worker.js:61:22
>   Remote event names: destroyed, crashed

to be noted I am working with windows OS, GIT bash and Atom text editor

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to put your commit message between `""` (double quotes) when editing said message in an editor (as opposed to the command-line `git commit -m "..."`).

Second, check how your Atom is set as a git commit message editor.

```
git config -l
```

[GitHub documents](https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/) for instance:

```
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

Comment: I made configuration using path to make it more accurate like this >> after unset the editor >> git config --global core.editor "‘path\atom.exe’ -n -w ". I think configuration is good otherwise the editor will not pop up as shown in the video.

Comment: @MohamedSheshtawy OK.  an you try in a CMD session where you set a minimal PATH, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53700095/6309