# Is it acceptable to use Git BASH for non-git tasks in Windows 10?

Tags: bash, git, terminal, command-line-interface

I've been using Git-BASH terminal for non-git tasks. I prefer to use and am more comfortable using a BASH terminal over the Windows PS or Command Prompt. Basically, I started looking into having a BASH terminal on Windows, when I realized I already have one.
Is there any technical/integrity/security risk to doing this?

Comment: Cygwin is another option. The main advantage being the package manager it has and thus the easily availability of additional programs / features

Comment: I use git bash all the time for sed / find / xargs etc all the time.

Comment: git bash is just an application combined with mingw - it's usefulness depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: It purely depends on who else might dislike that. If you are always the only user and you can always ensure Git Bash is there, feel free to do what you like.

Comment: If you find that git bash lacks some functionality you need, you might consider running a local linux vm.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "GitHub bash", only the git-bash packaged with [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

It is the only alternative to [WSL (the Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).

I usually use Git for Windows with a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54359814/6309), which means I have 200+ Linux command right from any shell session, even a simple CMD one.