# Does the Netbeans 8.2 GitHub facility really work in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, github, netbeans

I've been trying for the lase week to use GitHub from NB from a Windows 10 machine. Very little success.
The problem is the first Push step (Next) seems to time out will trying to connect, giving a Fail to Connect error. If Next is clicked again it often seems to connect... no more "failed to connect" message. However, the Finish step fails with a "cannot open git receive pack" message. On rare occasion, both steps succeed.

I am aware that there have been reported Windows 10 page load load time issues from the beginning, so am suspicious. But I report this thinking I am probably not the only person with the problem. For now, NB GitHub is useless. Too bad.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had a network issue. Recently page loads and other Internet operations have been slow, and finally stopped altogether. I rebooted my cable modem, presumably resulting in a new IP from my ISP (Spectrum). And now the Push is working

Answer (score 0):

Try first the first push from a [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) in a CMD session, possibly using a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54359814/6309), for testing.

If that does work, check if NetBeans has the same issue (pushing to a GitHub repo) with an HTTPS and/or an SSH URL.