# Git Bash - ssh-keygen not working (quits before generating RSA key pair)

Tags: bash, git, ssh, rsa

It's working fine with Eclipse default git extension and I can do each and every operation using it, I can even generate RSA key.

But when I access git remote using git bash, I got this error:

```
The authenticity of host '[hostname]:PORT ([IP Address]:PORT)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:U...M.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

and then I removed existing RSA key and tried to generate new RSA key pair and its starts and then quits before completion.

```
ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/userName/.ssh/id_rsa):
userName@example MINGW64 ~/git/path (branch name):
```

And I also tried to generate a new RSA key using GIT GUI,  I got below error

```
error writing "stdout": broken pipe
error writing "stdout": broken pipe
    while executing
"puts $::answer"
    (procedure "finish" line 9)
    invoked from within
"finish"
    invoked from within
".b.ok invoke"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's enough descriptive and comes under programming and it's not a plain coding problem where I could provide enough reproducible code. I saw various questions on Git and ssh is on this site. I don't understand why someone down vote it?

Comment: @OmChoudhary Is my answer below enough to solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a recent version of Git (2.19.2 or more), make sure to generate a PEM private SSH key, not an OPENSSH one.
See "[Jenkins: what is the correct format for private key in Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309)"

Use:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P "" -f afile
```

Then try again your git push, from a simple CMD (no need for bash), using a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54566962/6309):

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```