# GIT Issue on Windows (The filename or extension is too long)

Tags: windows, git

**Overview:**

Just installed the GIT version 2.20.1-64-bit on my Windows 7 platform. Git works well on GIT Bash; but, any git command on Windows CMD or Powershell raises **The filename or extension is too long** error.

**Details:**

- GIT version: 2.20.1-64-bit
- Platform: Windows 7

**Troubleshooting Efforts:**

I tried switching longpaths attribute to true based on  [Filename too long in Git for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows). I also googled to find other solutions but all recommended the same approach which was updating the git config.

- The GIT config file updated with `git config --system core.longpaths true` 
  [image]

Issue:

Any Git command via Windows CMD or 3rd party apps like IntelliJ Idea raises the following error:

- CMD: 
  [image]
- IntelliJ: 
  [image]

Please advise me with your genuine solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long when running main() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519558/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-when-running-main)

Comment: Note: this is when running `Git`, not related to a specified repo as your link said, so `core.longpaths` has no usage here.

Comment: I would like to know if the two lines you totally strike out in `git config --list` hurts.

Comment: Besides, I would like to know if `%PATH%` environment variable hurts.

Comment: Just had a look on the link, my issue is different. I reckon the root cause is `Git has a limit of 4096 characters for a filename, except on Windows when Git is compiled with msys. It uses an older version of the Windows API and there's a limit of 260 characters for a filename.` 

Commented out lines: 

    `http.sslcainfo=<Cert location>
    http.sslbackend=openssl`

Comment: Git bin directory added to the PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first to use a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54359814/6309) and a portable Git (like [`PortableGit-2.20.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.20.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.20.1-64-bit.7z.exe)) uncompressed anywhere you want.

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Then check if the issue persists in that CMD session, where you have set said simplified PATH.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. The portable version resolved the issue

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I then installed it in my user folder and now it works. It seems to be a privilege issue. Git gets installed as admin in *C:\Program Files\Git* but then can't write to these files because it is run as a user.

Also using the portable version should fix the problem.