# git clone failure with "--stdin requires a git repository"

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am puzzling on this issue and stuck here with no clue why it happens.

I am using git clone to get my repo from bitbucket like "git clone git@bitbucket.org:mycompny/therepo.git "

But, I am failed with something like:

```
fatal: --stdin requires a git repository
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that error message [introduced  in 2016 here](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqh963r12h.fsf@gitster.mtv.corp.google.com/T/):

> The index-pack builtin is marked as `RUN_SETUP_GENTLY`, because it's perfectly fine to index a pack in the filesystem outside of any repository.
>   However, `--stdin` mode will write the result to the object database, which does not
>   make sense outside of a repository. Doing so creates a bogus "`.git`" directory with nothing in it except the newly-created pack and its index.

The cause of the error is that the current folder is not a git directory.

Check your current folder, and make sure its path is an existing one.

Here, the root cause is using Cygwin, instead of the git bash included with [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

The [OP yunfei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1153026/yunfei) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59606279/git-clone-failure-with-stdin-requires-a-git-repository/59606902?noredirect=1#comment105512386_59606902):

> If I use the git included from my "`git bash`", by exporting it into my environment in cygwin, I can make it work from cygwin as well.
>
> Just do `export PATH="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd":$PATH`

Cygwin must include a Git version ([2.21 in the Cygwin package list](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/git.html)) which was not compatible with other components from [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases): using the `git.exe` from Git for Windows is safer.

Comment: Thanks VonC, I think the case in your link is different than mine. I am doing clone under a clean directory, there is no .git .

Comment: @yunfei the link is not about a "different case": it is about when and why that particular error message was introduced.

Comment: @yunfei What git version are you using, on which OS (and OS version)?

Comment: I am using git 2.21.0 on cygwin, I am using windows10. Thanks!

Comment: @yunfei cygwin? Don't use cygwin. A git bash maybe, but try it frst in a regular CMD, with a simplified PATH: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54624681/6309. And use for testing the 2.24.1

Comment: I can do the clone from my windows based ubuntu virtual machine.

Comment: @yunfei Exactly: 2.24 in a regular CMD with a simplified PATH should give you the same successful clone.

Comment: I have been getting used to cygwin for many years, then I may change my bad habit:(

Comment: @yunfei git bash included with Git for Windows will allow you to keep those same habits. Even a regular CMD will give you all the same Linux commands, it you are using the simplified PATH I recommended.

Comment: @yunfei let me (and others) know if it works with a simplified PATH (from a CMD, or a CMD where you typed 'bash', if you want to do so from a cygwin-like shell)

Comment: Hi VonC, I thought I confirmed it works from windows power shell, also works from git bash.

But my question was trying to understand how can my failure happen. Even I was using the cygwin git, and a different version, the error does not make sense to me.

Comment: If I use the git included from my "git bash", by exporting it into my environment in cygwin, I can make it work from cygwin as well.

Just do  export PATH="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd":$PATH

Comment: @yunfei Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I started getting this error and upgrading git on Cygwin fixed it for me, I'm not sure what caused it, but if you get this and want to use Cygwin's git then update it or remove and re-rinstall which worked for me.