# Why is git clone not working on MacOS Big Sur?

Tags: git, macos, macos-big-sur

After upgrading to Big Sur, git clone (using `git` version 2.30.2) no longer works.

When I enter the command `git clone ...` it outputs this:

> Cloning into 'git'...
> fatal: --stdin requires a git repository.
> fatal: index-pack failed.

An adding the verbose flag doesn't help much

> *$ git clone ... -v*
> Cloning into 'git'...
> POST git-upload-pack (164 bytes)
> POST git-upload-pack (gzip 40602 to 20426 bytes)
> fatal: --stdin requires a git repository
> fatal: index-pack failed

However, the other standard git commands, like push, diff, add, commit, status, etc, still work fine.

The only thing I've found online relates to [git on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59606279/git-clone-failure-with-stdin-requires-a-git-repository), but I don't think it's the same issue. Please help!

Before upgrading to Big Sur, git clone worked fine. I'm wondering if a dependency might have been updated/changed/removed during the upgrade.

Comment: try uninstalling and reinstalling it

Comment: did that, didn't work.

Comment: is only git clone is not working?

Comment: try cloning over ssh.

Comment: @GokulnathP yes, all other porcelain commands work fine. I haven't tried plumbing commands.

Comment: @Saqib it doesn't matter if it's https or ssh, I get the same error either way.

Comment: I faced the same issue, ssh + restart resolved it.

Comment: @Saqib didn't work for me

Comment: Where are you getting this version of git from?

Comment: Hold on, looks like there's a minor patch update for Big Sur. Let's see if this fixes anything.

Comment: Could we see `cd` output and complete `git clone` command?

Comment: Updating didn't fix the problem, but looks cloning works with the github desktop app. This kind of works, for now...

Comment: Use git clone to clone a remote repository.  The command by itself is useless.  Ex: `git clone https://github.com/user/repo/`

Comment: Thanks, but I know how git clone works. The `...` in my post is a placeholder for any repo. It doesn't matter what repo I clone, or whether it's over https or ssh, I get that error.

Comment: @langnostic Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running into this now, and it's maddening.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. I even tried to uninstall and reinstall xcode command line tools