# Cannot run Git in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I was trying to clone a Git repository using IntelliJ. The steps I performed were:
VCS -> Get from Version Control -> I filled in the repository URL and chose the Directory to store the codes -> Clone.

The process stopped and when I navigated to the target directory I can't see any of codes, the directory is still empty.

This is the error message I have obtained:

[image]

If the picture is not clear here is the message on it:

```
"Cannot Run Git
error launching git: The filename or extension is too long."
```

Comment: Try to execute `git config --system core.longpaths true`. It should help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GIT Issue on Windows (The filename or extension is too long)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622917/git-issue-on-windows-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long)

Comment: @s0xzwasd I have tried running this command but the error persists.I suspect the problem has to do with the integration with the IntelliJ.

Comment: I ran those commands and the error still existed. However, what I did was to go to Settings and re entered the path to my git installation and the error shown in the picture above did not appear.