# submodule is not a git command (with NPM on GIT for Windows)

Tags: node.js, git

When trying to make an install with NPM, an error occurs : 'submodule' is not a git command

Git bash for windows (version : 2.20.1.windows.1)

```
$ npm install
Unhandled rejection Error: Command failed: C:\PROGRAM FILES\GIT\mingw64\bin\git.EXE submodule update -q --init --recursive
git: 'submodule' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself.
```

I'm a beginner with GIT and I need your help to find a solution ?! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again with use a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54359814/6309) and a portable Git (like [`PortableGit-2.20.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.20.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.20.1-64-bit.7z.exe)) uncompressed anywhere you want.

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
set PATH=c:\path\to\npm;%PATH%
```

Then check if the issue persists in that CMD session (where you have set said simplified PATH) with your `npm install` command.

Comment: Using portable GIT solved this specific problem. Thanks !