# I cannot push local modification using TortoiseGit

Tags: windows, git, debian, tortoisegit

I need your help, actually I have installed git on my debian server then create my remote repository on it. And I have also installed tortoisegit on my windows client.

I have cloned my repository from my debian server to my windows client without problem but I facing a problem, when I make modification on my local repository(windows client) and try to push to my remote repository (debian server) using TortoiseGit.

It stuck at:

```
git.exe push --progress "origin" master:master
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 249 bytes | 62.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

And can't close the window, have the progress bar, I have only one option "abort".

Can someone have been confronted to similar situation? Or can someone help me please?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include more information:  Are you connecting with SSH or HTTP?  Are you using a git hosting platform on Debian, or is it *just* a git repository?

Comment: it is a git repository and on my windows client i'm using tortoisegit to push. it is with ssh.

Answer (score 1):

Try the same push using the command line, with a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54359814/6309) and a portable Git (like [`PortableGit-2.20.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.20.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.20.1-64-bit.7z.exe)) uncompressed anywhere you want.

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

See if the push succeeds there.
If not, check the state of the remote repo by connecting to the server, and running a `git status` in the target bare repo.