# Vim create more junk files and cannot be removed by rm -rf on gitbash on windows 10

Tags: vim, git-bash

Just upgrade gitbash to last version. 
Then tried to create file using vim editor on gitbash.
File could be created but it created several files along with,

```
test.txt
test_txt.swp
.test.txt.swp
.test.txt.swx
```

And when I tried to remove using

```
rm -rf test.txt
```

message error: `rm: cannot remove test.txt: invalid request code`

Comment: Did you exit vim before trying your rm?

Comment: Yes, I did and even tried to close git-bash and reopened and tried again. Same thing still happened.

Comment: I suppose the simplified path did not work then ?

Comment: I downgraded to previous version. Everything works back as normal. That's odd!

Answer (score 0):

[Invalid request code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326811/7490) seems to be `EBADRQC 56`

To be sure this is not a `PATH` issue, where a Cygwin installation might interfer with the mingw bash for Git for Windows, try the same command in a [simplified `PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54359814/6309) and a portable Git (like [`PortableGit-2.23.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.23.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.23.0-64-bit.7z.exe)), uncompressed anywhere you want.

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Then try the `rm` command in a regular Windows CMD shell session (not `git bash` at first).

Try and use (for testing) `rm -i`, to get confirmation. `-f` is a bit dangerous, `-rf` even more so.